# SSL security exception [Security:090542] issue=> invalid API key response from server

Tags: java, web-services, web

Hi Web service professionals,

I am running into this ssl exception [Security:090542] issue. Here is the whole message

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090542]Certificate
>   chain received from localhost - 127. . . --> api.company.com was not
>   trusted causing SSL handshake failure. Check the certificate chain to
>   determine if it should be trusted or not. If it should be trusted,
>   then update the client trusted CA configuration to trust the CA
>   certificate that signed the peer certificate chain. If you are
>   connecting to a WLS server that is using demo certificates (the
>   default WLS server behavior), and you want this client to trust demo
>   certificates, then specify -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust
>   on the command line for this client.

I would like to get your input to how to resolve the issue. I am not sure on how to approach to solve this issue. Should I convert the AccessKey from Java String to XML? If so what is the method to do it? Or what is the main issue that I am facing?  Thank you for all of your input. Here is the part of SOAP requirement message that relates to the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<SendEmployee xmlns="http://api.company.com/">
<request accessKey="string">
```

Here is my proxy class that relates to the accessKey

```
public class SendEmployeeRequest {
    /**
     * Sets the value of the accessKey property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAccessKey(String value) {
        this.accessKey = value;
    }
}
```

---

In my main Java program that sends out the string AccessKey to webservice for authentication, I have 2 line of code to set the API Accesskey that supplied to me by vendor.

```
SendEmployeeRequest employeeRequest = objectFactory.createSendEmployeeRequest();
employeeRequest.setAccessKey("nOzbwpMGMbeEXTU=");
```